# How to avoid overwriting context in nested components (like Tabs) in Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

Best-practice for negotiating between parent and child components is using `context`. For instance, [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/31459a9e237941a2b934c05a469a4dae?version=3.55.0) is an implementation for `Tabs` and `Tab` component: `TabPanel` will be visible by clicking on related `Tab`.

If we use nested `Tabs`, higher level context values will be overwritten by the child `Tabs` (context key is the same).

```
<!-- Tabs.svelte -->
<script context="module">
    export const TABS = {};
</script>
```

And, to access to context:

```
<!-- TabPanel.svelte -->
<script>
    import { getContext } from 'svelte';
    import { TABS } from './Tabs.svelte';

    const panel = {};
    const { registerPanel, selectedPanel } = getContext(TABS);

    registerPanel(panel);
</script>

{#if $selectedPanel === panel}
    <slot></slot>
{/if}
```

In this [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/31459a9e237941a2b934c05a469a4dae?version=3.55.0), if you click on the second tab inside the first root tabs, then click on the second/third tab of the root tabs, the selected tab for the child tabs will be changed.

How can we separate contexts in child components to avoid applying un-wanted changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the context. Contexts can be overridden in descendants without interfering with the parent context, it just hides that.

The problem is that the entire tab content gets destroyed when the tab is not visible and thus the selection is lost. If instead of using an `{#if}` you just hide the content, the selection is retained (even without binding to some local state).

e.g.

```html
<!-- In TabPanel.svelte -->
<div style:display={$selectedPanel === panel ? 'block' : 'none'}>
    <slot></slot>
</div>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/e7d9b19612774f33aa8854b3ff96aefa?version=3.55.0)

Comment: My issue is not just showing/hiding the TabPanel, it is just an example. I would like to know how to have separated contexts in nested components (Tabs, Accordions, etc.). I know I can implement with store: store is accessible to all components (not child components). Each context has a key and I am looking for a solution to generate unique key for context.

Comment: That does not work. If you were to generate different keys, the other components would have no way of knowing it. Separate context keys should be used for groups of components that work together; nesting, as shown, is generally just not an issue.

Comment: That's my point: I generate a random key for each component. Then, how the child components inside slot can get access to the generated key? How the children will know what was their parent's key?

Comment: As I said, you should *not* and don't need to.

Comment: Thanks, I got your point, but if we should use style to show/hide, why Svelte has if block?!

Comment: There is no simple "only use this" rule. Using `{#if}` removes unused elements, which uses less memory but loses state and the elements have to be recreated which is more expensive. On the other hand hiding elements requires more memory and can potentially slow down the window, if there is too much stuff in the DOM.

Comment: @AmirPournasserian I just want to say thank you for this elegant context-based tab demo  Secondly, to help prove @h-b’s point (and for my own reference) I created https://svelte.dev/repl/f2981102a577452a9a6c656680ea8671?version=4.2.0 which just switches to using styles/classes to hide/show tab panel content instead of `if` statements (which completely remove/add DOM elements, thus preventing you from maintaining state)